# Android Facebook Logout error (Unknown Method)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, logout

Im using Facebook SDK to get basic user Information.
I can log in, but I can't log out.
For Logging out, I used this code

```
public void logoutFromFacebook() {
mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response) {
        Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    }
});
}
```

Inside the log: Response was:

> {"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method","request_args":[{"key":"access_token","value":"CAAIHzpeuZAgcBAP9Ik9zAkVYoqEPQH4pIU3GDX0nmOFPGygHhzUrHXn3qKiiCZA4bmcE5tHg8cT1JcfWkoep1ZC3JmmmGUktT45GiDHqJUDvqzrxyaTqP6ZCcTcAbaZBkEmAbmitwd2xll5okZAXlElLKPxE3LEGdPE3FB9mmzyQZDZD"},{"key":"method","value":"auth.expireSession"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}

Could you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `AsyncFacebookRunner` is deprecated so you should avoid using it. Because this class is deprecated the code is no longer supported and is therefore unreliable. This could be the reason why you are receiving your error. Now, if you use the newer `Facebook SDK`, 3.1 I believe it is, it is very easy to log out:

```
Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

[Here's some more information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/AsyncFacebookRunner) on the `AsyncFacebookRunner` class. [And here's their](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) "Getting Started" page where they provide easy setup instructions and tutorials to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

try By changing **this to your activityName.this** this may solve your Problem

```
public void logoutFromFacebook() {
// changes ares Required in Following line
mAsyncRunner.logout(yourActivityName.this, new RequestListener() {

@Override
public void onComplete(String response) {
    Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);

    }
}

@Override
public void onIOException(IOException e) {
}

@Override
public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e) {
}

@Override
public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
}

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
}
```

});
}

also you can Visit Following link, This May Help You :)

[facebook sdk in android app, only able to login, but not able to logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334545/by-using-facebook-sdk-in-android-app-only-able-to-login-but-not-able-logout)